# Importing Arabic Wordnet with python 3.4

Tags: python, python-3.x, wordnet

I am trying to get synonyms with Arabic wordnet, I found an old answer, so they used WordNet with an older version of python

I download the database

- http://nlp.lsi.upc.edu/awn/get_bd.php

and the program the read the Wordnet

- http://nlp.lsi.upc.edu/awn/AWNDatabaseManagement.py.gz

Now when I execute the code

```
AWNDatabaseManagement.py -i upc_db.xml
```

I have this error message:

```
Unable to create process using '/pkg/ldc/bin/python2.1
"C:\arabic-train\AWNDatabaseManagement.py"  -i awn.xml'
```

How to fix that, It seems a version problem since I am using python 3.4.
Reagrds

Comment: looks your python location could be specified using the unix file path format. And it seems that you are using windows.... **/pkg/ldc/bin/python2.1** is a unix file path format where as **C:\arabic-train\AWNDatabaseManagement.py** is a windows file path format

Comment: yes i find this in the beginning of the program #!/pkg/ldc/bin/python2.1, how to fix that?

Comment: I would remove the **#!/pkg/ldc/bin/python2.1** line and see what happens. This line was used by the author to specify a python virtual environment to use when running this file. However, as this venv doesn't exist on your system the line is worth removing.